# sql query: If a field is a prefix of a key

Tags: sql

I have a few records in my table.
I want to get all records where field "x" is a prefix of some key. In other words
say i have 3 records where field "x" in first record is ***abc***, in second ***abcd***, in third ***xyz***. And I want to get all records where x is a prefix of ***abcdefg***.

```
    |--------x--------|
    |_________________|
   1|-----abc---------|
   2|-----abcd--------|
   3|-----xyz---------|
```

I want to select records where value of field x is a prefix of abcdefg, I can write something like

```
select *
from table
where x in (a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde, abcdef, abcdefg)
```

But is there a better solution

Comment: select * from table where x like 'abc%' or x like 'abcd%' or x like 'xyz%' ?  Not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: @user1745356 your question is not clear. You described 3 *different* values for **x**. Consider providing a clearer (and full) example.

Comment: SQL is a language. Which SQL-product are you using? SQL-Server, MySQL, DB2, Oracle, Postgres, Firebird, SQlite, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Using MS SQL Server:

```
select * from [tablex] where left([x], 1) = 'a' and charindex([x], 'abcdefg') = 1
```

Or just:

```
select * from [tablex] where charindex([x], 'abcdefg') = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/111a3/1

Comment: downvoter care to explain!? ***"where x is a prefix of abcdefg"***

Comment: His input is ``abcdefg`` and he is looking for all the rows that match

Comment: Don't get mad, look as at his fixed question

Comment: Anyway, I upvoted you. I just wanted you to see that your SQL is incorrect, as far as I can tell, but if you are getting mad, the purpose was lost

Comment: An example of ``x`` that matches but should't ``aabcdefg``

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres (this is standard SQL):

```
WHERE 'abcdefg' LIKE x || '%'
```

For Oracle, MySQL, Postgres:

```
WHERE 'abcdefg' LIKE CONCAT(x,'%')
```

For SQL-Server:

```
WHERE 'abcdefg' LIKE x + '%'
```

---

But what you have, i.e.:

```
WHERE x IN ('', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'abcdefg')
```

is probably the **most efficient** solution and should work in almost all DBMS.